# bash script for many files in parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have read similar questions about this topic but none of them help me with the following problem:

I have a bash script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename  in /home/user/Desktop/emak/*.fa; do
    mkdir ${filename%.*}
    cd ${filename%.*}
    mkdir emak
    cd ..
done
```

This script basically does the following:

- Iterate through all files in a directory
- Create a new directory with the name of each file
- Go inside the new file and create a new file called "emak"

The real task does something much computational expensive than create the "emak" file...

I have about thousands of files to iterate through.
As each iteration is independent from the previous one, I will like
to split it in different processors ( I have 24 cores) so I can do multiples files at the same time.

I read some previous post about running in parallel (using: GNU) but I do not see a clear way   to apply it in this case.

thanks

Comment: Have you made an attempt yourself using GNU parallel? It would be good to see that.

Comment: parallel -j $((`getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN`-1)) <your script name>

Comment: BTW, run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ to have quoting bugs found automatically so we don't need to point them out here. (If you had spaces in your filenames, the current code would behave badly).

Comment: @rai Default is number of cores. -j-1 == number of cores minus one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this with GNU Parallel, whereby you create and export a bash function called `doit`:

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
    dir=${1%.*}
    mkdir "$dir"
    cd "$dir"
    mkdir emak
}
export -f doit
parallel doit ::: /home/user/Desktop/emak/*.fa
```

You will really see the benefit of this approach if the time taken by your *"computationally expensive"* part is longer, or especially *variable*. If it takes, say up to 10 seconds and is variable, GNU Parallel will submit the next job as soon as the shortest of the N parallel processes completes, rather than waiting for all N to complete before starting the next batch of N jobs.

As a crude benchmark, this takes 58 seconds:

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
   echo $1
   # Sleep up to 10 seconds
   sleep $((RANDOM*11/32768))
}
export -f doit
parallel -j 10 doit ::: {0..99}
```

and this is directly comparable and takes 87 seconds:

```
#!/bin/bash
N=10
for i in {0..99}; do
    echo $i
    sleep $((RANDOM*11/32768)) &
    (( ++count % N == 0)) && wait
done
```

Comment: Sure, though in this particular case I'd argue that the overhead of spinning up a new child-process shell to run each copy of this function per directory will be far, far more expensive than the time saved by the parallelization itself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OP says that the actual process is *"far more computationally expensive"*

Comment: *sigh*. I wish people would put a `sleep 3 # do something expensive here` in their examples to demonstrate that kind of thing.

Comment: This one works really well!! Each iteration takes 47seconds.  with the doit functions it takes 50 seconds to do 24 iterations. I tried with 48 files (48 iterations) and it takes 100 seconds. It works in blocks of 24, it seems to me that it does in this way because I have 24 cores. am I right?
thanks so much!

Comment: Correct! You can also use `parallel --eta` to get an estimate of when it will finish (Estimated Time of Arrival) and `parallel -j 16` to run on 16 cores, for example. Also, if you have multiple servers available, you can distribute the jobs across multiple machines just by adding them to the command line - check any GNU Parallel tutorial. To be fair to @chepner you should change his `N=10` to `N=24`.

Answer (score 7):

No need for `parallel`; you can simply use

```
N=10
for filename in /home/user/Desktop/emak/*.fa; do
    mkdir -p "${filename%.*}/emak" &
    (( ++count % N == 0)) && wait
done
```

The second line pauses every Nth job to allow all the previous jobs to complete before continuing.

Comment: Nice. Also, much more efficient than the GNU parallel approach of spinning up new shell instances.

Comment: ...though really, reducing the number of individual `mkdir` calls would help performance even further. Perhaps one might want to pipe into `xargs -0 -P 0 mkdir -p`? That also avoids the wasted CPU from waiting for all N processes to finish whenever we get to a `wait` before starting a new batch.

Comment: I started working on something like `find ... -exec mkdir -p {} +`, but lost interest in figuring out how to combine that with stripping `.fa` from `filename`. Free rep for anyone who wants to pursue that! :)

Comment: `-exec bash -c 'mkdir -p "${@%.*}"' {} +`, perhaps?

Comment: That strips the `.fa`, but doesn't add `/emak` to each.

Comment: Hmm. `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do printf '%s\0' "${filename%.*}/emak"; done | xargs -0 mkdir -p --`?